# Sorting array of random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, math, methods, random

Hey guys looking for some help with my ArrayTester class...
The array is supposed to
1.create a 20 element int array and populates it with random elements in the range 20 through 65 (both inclusive).
-I Believe I have already done this.

2.Use the java.util.Random class with a seed of 2621 to generate repeatable output for the data.
-I have also already done this

3.The tester class should then test each of these methods(mean, median, mode, max, min, standard divination)
-this is where I'm having trouble, I already have the code for the mean, mode, max, min, and standard divination.. the problem I'm having is with the median as i would like to sort my array in the tester class before having it called by my main Class.

Is there any way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
public class ArrayTest
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int[] numbers;
        numbers = new int [20];
        Random rand = new Random(2621); 
        int maxRange = 65;
        int minRange = 20;

        for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = rand.nextInt(maxRange - minRange + 1) + minRange;
            //checks to see if printing out ocrrectly
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Standard "deviation."  "Divination" involves slaughtering small animals and looking at their entrails.   `Arrays.sort`

Comment: "standard divination": Do you mean "standard deviation"?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Arrays.sort(numbers);`

Comment: I know that but if I put it right before the system.out.println I keep getting an error

Comment: You have to do this **after** the loop, otherwise your array will not be fully populated.

Comment: I'm having trouble even with that, as of right now when I put the Arrays.sort(numbers); outside the for loop nothing changes when I outprint the array (the numbers are still printing out, they're just not sorted) This made me believe that I had to also move my System.out.println(numbers[i]) outside the for loop as well. However when I do this I get an error saying that it cannot find the variable [i]

Comment: You will need 2 loops, fist to generate the random numbers which you already have and then call`Arrays.sort` and then another loop to print the array again which will be now sorted